# A differ from B by/due to/for the presence of C?

Tags: prepositions

My question is whether one should use "by", "due to", "for", or something else in a sentence like, for example:

"Mineral water differs from distilled water by/due to/for the presence of minerals"

or in general

"A differs from B by/due to/for the presence of C"

Which one is correct, "by", "due to", or "for"? Or maybe one should use another preposition? Or maybe all these possibilities are correct, but they convey a slightly different meaning?

Comment: I should say "due to" is the word I would choose. "For" is ok too. But I am not sure anout "by". Nativers may provide a better answer.

Comment: Well, I would use "for" or "due to" as well, but I would really like to know the opinion of an English mother tongue

Comment: To me, "by" and "due to" (or "because of") give different meanings here. "Due to" means that the presence of C *causes* some difference between A and B (without specifying the difference); "by" means that the presence of C *is* the difference between A and B.  (And "for" seems simply wrong in this context.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass I feel that "by" is the right choice when the difference is something measurable, like in the example "My height differs from yours by 5 inches". But would it be correct to use a phrase like "by the presence of"?

Comment: If someone downvotes the question, I would like to know the reason, so that I could improve this question and the questions I would ask in the future

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you are trying to communicate.

If you are speaking of a measure difference you might use 'by' indicating a measured differing amount.
E.g. My height differs from yours by 5 inches

If you are showing a cause of the difference you would use 'due to'
E.g. Mineral water differs from distilled water due to the distilling process.

If you are looking for a purpose then you would use for
E.g. A lion differs from a tiger for many reasons; however the lion is simply stronger.

Comment: Excellent answer. Could you comment also on the cases like "A differs from B by/due to/for the presence of C"? What you would use before "the presence of C", i.e., in the case that the difference is the presence of a specific property, which is present in A and absent in B?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=differs+from+it+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cdiffers%20from%20it%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdiffers%20from%20it%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdiffers%20from%20it%20only%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdiffers%20from%20it%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdiffers%20from%20it%20essentially%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdiffers%20from%20it%20chiefly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdiffers%20from%20it%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdiffers%20from%20it%20so%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdiffers%20from%20it%20very%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdiffers%20from%20it%20considerably%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bdiffers%20from%20it%20and%3B%2Cc0), the two most common prepositions after *"differs from it"* are *by* and *in*.

For this particular sentence I would not use *in* because *in the presence of minerals* could mean something else (namely, they only differ when minerals are nearby). 
So let's pick a different sentence. Here are three possible wordings:

> Lions differ from cats in their size.
>   Lions differ from cats in that they are bigger.
>   Lions differ from cats by being bigger.

The grammar is rather complicated here ... I wouldn't put a noun after *by*, but a noun works perfectly well after *in*. I can also put a clause after *in that*, and a present participle (with the subject of *lions*) after *by*.

Using *because* or *due to* says that the reason lions differ from cats are that they are bigger, which may or may not be the meaning that you intend.

And your final suggestion, *for*, doesn't work at all in English—your thinking it might could be influenced by your native language.

Comment: Indeed "for" is the most natural choice for me...as you said it may be influenced by being a non-native speaker. Anyway in my question the phrase "the presence of ..." is an important part. In other words, the main difference between A and B is *the presence* of the property C. In general, there is no obvious way to rephrase a sentence like this as you did using a particular example.

Comment: *A* differs from *B* by having the property *C*; *A* differs from *B* because of the presence of the property *C*; *A* differs from *B* in that the property *C* is present in *A*.

Comment: I would say that "A differs from B due to the presence of C", "A differs from B because of the presence of C". I like more the first option "due to" despite silenceinlife's opinion.

Comment: The copyeditor suggested "by" which is totally weird for me

Comment: I think *due to* works fine ... the distinction between *due to* and *because of* that silenceinlife is complaining about is pretty much archaic. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+lost+due+to%2Cwas+lost+because+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwas%20lost%20due%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwas%20lost%20because%20of%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Ok so I think this would be a good solution for my specific case.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of due to:

> Due

...is an adjective, and **cannot** be used as a preposition. A more correct term (closely related) would be owing to, which is grammatically correct. If you are strictly concerned about grammar then you will need to take that into account in your writing. **Otherwise, it is natural to use *due to*.**

> "A differs from B *due to* X,Y,Z" ✓

In the above, we are saying that due to properties X,Y,Z a difference exists between object A and object B.

For is indeed a preposition (as you will see in most texts) however it is not the right word choice given the sentence structure and wording you have provided.

If you are looking to use *for* in your sentence, it can be used as a coordinating conjunction. This means it can be used to provide rationale between two phrases, sentences, objects etc EG

What is the reason that Jeremiah sliced his cat?

> Jeremiah was hungry. Jeremiah then went and sliced his cat.

The reason (i.e. rationale for) that Jeremiah sliced his cat was, because, he was hungry.

We can then say:

> "Jeremiah sliced his cat up, for he was hungry" ✓

You can use *for* in your sentence to explain that the difference between A and B is because of X,Y,Z however you would have to "elaborate further" to provide a rationale for such a distinction eg:

> "Mineral water differs from distilled water, for the presence of [X],[Y],[Z] in mineral water give it a different boiling point/texture/reactivity"

In the example above using the word *for*, we have achieved the same thing as we did using *due to*. However, you can see that it is much more natural and easier to use *due to* in this case because the sentence will not be as long.

I would use *because*:

> Mineral water differs from distilled water because of the presence of minerals.

in other words:

> "A differs from B *because of* X,Y,Z" ✓

Comment: Please give a reason WHY this was downvoted.  This gives the author a way to correct his solution.  Downvoting with no reason stated does not add value.

Comment: @silenceislife If you repost your answer without the boondoggle about *for*, and without the tautology reference, I'll upvote it for *owing to* and *because of*. The distinction between coordination and preposition is a good point also.

Comment: The statement can be tautological but it was just an example. The real sentence I have in mind is slightly different, and not tautological, but I cannot write the sentence here for many reason. Think more about "A differs from B by/due to/for the presence of C", and fill A, B, and C with anything you like.

Comment: The real sentence I have in mind is in the form  "A differs from B by/due to/for the presence of C" where A, B, and C are mathematical object. Anyway it really does not matter what A, B, and C are, because my doubt is only about the grammar. So please consider my question as a question about the grammar, not about logic. I recognize that the example I choose is kind of poor, but I don't  think it is strictly tautological. By the way I notice that many prepositions in math, like definitions of new concepts, may seem tautological at the first sight.

Comment: @PeterShor I made the criticism of its tautological nature because perhaps the OP was working on that sentence in particular, which is a safe assumption to make given the pattern of questions on this site. It is not clear to me that OP picked it because it was an obvious example, because nothing explicit was mentioned as such.

Comment: @PhilSweet Given that OP was on the right track in picking out 'by/due to' in his original sentence, as compared to picking out for, I thought I would make that distinction clear. 

I will nonetheless restructured my response, as I originally wrote in a hurry. I will also remove the tautological response as I have found out OP picked his sentence as an example, and not as a specific case he is on.

Comment: @silenceislife "If you are strictly concerned about grammar then you will need to take that into account in your writing. Otherwise, it is natural to use due to." Do you read things you write usually? If "due to" is used in common written English, even in the formal register (I read "due to" many times in journals where I am contributing, which are read internationally), **thus** it is correct. That's all. This innuendo about not being concerned about grammar is kind of offensive, and it is also totally non-sense in a place like this

Comment: @sintetico I would like to emphasise the "strictly" in "strictly concerned". If one aims to stick to the most widely accepted grammatical conventions and also to grammatical conventions that generate the least controversy, then one would not use due to prepositionally. There are many prepositions in the English language in place of it. Prepositions are part of closed classes, which do not readily accept new elements. Hence it is preferred that "due to" not be used prepositionally. This is a valid viewpoint held by many. It is ignorant to dismiss such a viewpoint because of anecdotal evidence.

Comment: I repeat the question: do you read things you write? Please proof-read what you write. If you do, the next time please avoid being offensive, as you were many times here already.

Comment: If something is used many times in the corpus of a given language, it is not "anecdotal evidence", it is indeed the norm. Anyway, you can have whatever opinion you have, it is not my problem, but please don't be offensive. I am not here to take insults.

Comment: Let's please not let the conversation digress from what the original topic is.  Yes, there are technical differences and yes everyone has a point if they wish to make a logical split about certain answers.  This is not a forum for personal degradation and nor is it a forum for proving that one person is right over the next.  Please present your answer and let the OP decide or discuss the solution that was provided rather than argue about viewpoints and why it doesn't agree with another viewpoint.

Comment: I try to proofread what I write most of the time, yes. I do not intend anything I write to be offensive (I don't think I would ever intend that). I apologies for any confusion or misunderstandings if so. Although I disagree with you, I do respect your viewpoint and I did enjoy our discussion. You are free to make your own mind up about the matter. 

Thank you.